# What is wrong with the program?

Tags: c

I'm extremely new to C and am doing a few problems I found in a book I bought. What is wrong with this program?

```
int main (void)
{
char text[50]='\0';
scanf ("%s", text);

printf("%c", text[49]);
printf("%s", text);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats the error? Whats the expected vs given outputs? Whats the input?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Line 3. You cant assign a single character to a character array. If you instead wrote `char text[50]="\0";` then it would be a different story.

Answer (score 8):

```
char text[50]='\0';
```

is not valid.  You could skip initialising `text` and just declare it

```
char text[50];
```

or you could initialise its first element

```
char text[50]={'\0'};
```

You're also missing an include of `stdio.h` and should really check that your `scanf` call read a string and could give it a max length for the string

```
if (scanf("%49s", text) == 1)
```

Comment: Or simpler (if you want to emphasize that text is a NUL-terminated string): `char text[50] = "";`

Comment: `char text[50] = {'\0'};` initializes all 50 elements of text, and not just the first.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, but only the first element is explicitly initialised. The remaining 49 elements are initialised using the same rules as for variables with static duration.  It just so happens that these rules give the remaining elements the same value that we explicitly selected for the first element.

Comment: @Anonymous, both initializations are exactly the same, only a different notation for it. Any initialization of an array initializes all elements of that array.

Answer (score 3):

You want to get rid of:

```
printf("%c", text[49]);
```

as you have no idea what's at that memory location if the string is less than 49 `char`s long.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference of single quotes and double quotes in C.

- double quotes means string
- single quotes means character

Line 3 will not compile because the compiler wants you to assign a string to the array of characters.

You can do

```
char text[50]="\0";
```

which in effect fills all the 50 bytes with zeros.

You could also do

```
char text[50]="bla";
```

which fills the first 3 bytes with "bla" and the rest with zeros. At least my compiler does it like that.

You could also do nothing because you anyway fill it with user input just the next statement.

```
char text[50];
scanf ("%s", text);
```

But then you have a problem. Because the very next statement will give you random output if the user has entered a string with less than 49 characters. But if you initialize, well then you output the zero byte, which is also quite useless.

The main point however is to learn the different behaviour of C when dealing with an array of characters.

Comment: "char text[50]="\0"; which in effect fills all the 50 bytes with zeros." All 50 or just 1?

Comment: All 50 bytes. I was actually surprised. I debugged it with XCode on my Mac. I am not sure if this is standard behaviour and what literature about ANSI C says about this. But treating the array of characters like a string makes sense. If every compiler does fill up the rest of the array with zeros is something I would not rely on. ANSI standard or not ANSI standard.

Comment: I agree that you may observe that behavior,. but I wouldn't count on it. Use char text[50] = { 0 }; to fill up all 50. Or text[50] = { '\0' };

Comment: I agree on this and this is what I wanted to express in my last post.

Comment: @hol The C language guarantees that every remaining element of an array will be initialised (to zero) if you supply an initialiser list that doesn't cover every element.  See e.g. C11 6.7.9.21 for details

Answer (score 1):

```
int main ()
{
char text[50]={'1','2','3','4'};
printf("%c", text[1]);
printf("%c",text[0]);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

do like this..